# How to create multi examples with create-next-app

Tags: next.js, i18next

I'm using this in order to create an Next app

https://open.segment.com/create-next-app/

but I'm facing this:

```
create-next-app --example with-next-i18next with-next-sass with-next-seo next-learn
```

I got this error

Could not locate an example named "with-next-i18next". Please check your spelling and try again.

but I want multiple examples, is that possible?

thanks in advance
Carlos Vieira

Answer (score 1):

Two things here:

- The error is because `with-next-i18next` is unknown to create-next-app. If you know where to find the template, you can use the URL to the Github repository with: [`create-next-app --example [github-url]`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/create-next-app#options).
- About using multiple examples: [as of August 2020 it was not possible to use multiple examples with `create-next-app`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/16626).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use at least Node 12.
On Node 10 I had the same error ("Could not locate an example named X...") on every example initialisation, switching to Node 12 solved the problem.